# How to fix the starting time of each calculation on MTF

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am new to learning pinescript and having a problem in fixing the time when creating a multi-timeframe indicator.

When i am using a 5-minute chart and I want to calculate the 4-hour MACD, the system will call the last 240-minute data for the plotting instead of starting from every 0/4/8/12 hours from noon.

For example, when the time is now 13:40, the latest 4-hour MACD values will be calculated from the data from 09:41 to 13:40, while i only want the date from 08:00 and then 12:00 because the results came out are different.

How could I do that?

Below is how i code currently:

```
min_open = request.security (syminfo.tickerid, "5", open)    
min_close = request.security (syminfo.tickerid, "5", close)    
hour_open = request.security (syminfo.tickerid, "60", open)    
hour_close = request.security (syminfo.tickerid, "60", close)    
h4_open = request.security (syminfo.tickerid, "240", open)    
h4_close = request.security (syminfo.tickerid, "240", close)

[macd, signal, hist] = ta.macd (h4_close, 12, 26, 9)

hline (0, "Zero Line", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))    
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.sytle_columns, color=(hist>=0? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))    
plot(macd, title="MACD"), color=color.red    
plot(signal, title="Signal"), color=color.blue
```

Comment: What's your ticker id and what's your chart's timezone set to?

Comment: currently i m learning with btcusdt and timezone is utc-4 as i want to run a 24x7 strategy test first, i haven't learnt that part if the market is closed yet.